# Issue with session array in php

Tags: php, session

I have created one session array in PHP and give it condition if a session is already created then push into that array and if not created then create session and push row in it but when I check with the condition I receive session is not created

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $quiz_session = Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 41 [Question] => abc ) );
  if (isset($_SESSION["quiz_question"])) {
     $_SESSION['quiz_question'] = array();
     $quiz_question = $_SESSION['quiz_question'];
     array_push($_SESSION['quiz_question'], array('Question' => $quiz_session[0]['Question'],'selected' => $Answer));
  }else{
     array_push($_SESSION['quiz_question'], array('Question' => 
     $quiz_session[0]['Question'],'selected' => $Answer));
   }
   print_r($_SESSION['quiz_question']);
?>
```

can anybody help me in this

Comment: What is `quiz_session` ?

Comment: it is one function from which we get an array

Comment: Please.. provide `var_dump($quiz_session);` and `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 41
            [Question] => abc
        )

)

Comment: @MNJ edit your question and include the code of quiz_session.